# How to rewrite the APIView's `post` method?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How to rewrite the APIView's `post` method?

I try to rewrite the post method like bellow, but seems it miss something.

```
class CloudServerShutdownAPIView(APIView):
    """
    shut down the server
    """
    serializer_class = CloudServerShutdownSerializer
    def post(self, request):
        cloudserver_id = request.data.pop("cloudserver_id")
        try:
            openstackServerShutdown(server_or_id=cloudserver_id)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response(data="shut down server fail", status=HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, exception=e)
```

How can I rewrite the post method correctly?

---

**EDIT**

The traceback is bellow:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 491, in dispatch
    self.response = self.finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 406, in finalize_response
    % type(response)
AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working?

Comment: @Exprator I just don't know whether this is correct?

Comment: did you run it?? did you get any error?

Comment: @Exprator Yes, I get error. I will put to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class CloudServerShutdownAPIView(APIView):
    """
    shut down the server
    """
    serializer_class = CloudServerShutdownSerializer
    def post(self, request):
        cloudserver_id = request.data.pop("cloudserver_id")
        try:
            openstackServerShutdown(server_or_id=cloudserver_id)
            return Response(data="shut down server successful", status=HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response(data="shut down server fail", status=HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, exception=e)
```

that is because you were not sending any response during the successful shutdown